# iOS: Writing tests for blocks

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to write a test for a function that takes in a `success` and `failure` block. Here was my first attempt at a test:

```
- (void)testThatValidSearchProducesSearchResults
{
    __block NSArray *searchResults;
    __block NSError *searchError;

    [self.searchQuery searchForPlaces:@"The White House"
                          success:^(NSArray *places) {
                              searchResults = places;
                          }
                          failure:^(NSError *error) {
                              searchError = error;
                          }
     ];

    XCTAssertNotNil(searchResults, @"Valid search should return search results.");
    XCTAssertNil(searchError, @"Valid search should not return an error.");
}
```

The code in the blocks is never executed before the test conditions are reached, however. Thoughts on testing this accurately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without being able to see the contents of searchQuery, the most likely response seems to be "its probably an asynchronous API" - you are queueing up a request, not performing it.

As such, you fall through into the asserts before the request has finished one way or the other and thus neither success: or failure: blocks will have been invoked.  That should be expected behaviour.

Now, if its not asynchronous, then congratulations, your test has found a bug - in the function being tested.

Comment: I get that im queuing up a request. What I'm wondering is how to write a test that actually tests the functionality of the searchForPlaces function instead of falling through

Comment: Since the test is expected to be performed synchronously, the only way it can test asynchronous functions is to have it wait for completion one way or another.  I would guess some kind of runloop waiting for one or the other completion methods to fire, or a timer to expire.

Comment: Or, you could change what you expect to test.  Look through the queue to see if the request is actually queued, and declare it a success if it is, and a failure if it isn't.  Which probably requires mocking the queue...

Synchronous testing of async functions is never going to be trivial.